# Does sun HttpServer have something like session?

Tags: java

I want to create session between http client and server using simple sun HttpServer. I need it because client must be able to open session (providing loginname/password) and session must be auto destroyed after some time. Is there anything like this? Or maybe there are solutions to get it?

I tried to find in internet but found nothing.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask. What have you tried so far? What is the problem you have when using/writing a session system? What are the errors you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the `com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer` has no concept of a Session.

It's a very low level server implementation.

Anything like session management would be implemented by your custom code.

If you want something to manage sessions for you, you'd be better off embedding some other solution (such as embeddable Jetty or Tomcat).

Answer (score 0):

what Will said is true but its fairly easy to create a session like management and i thought ill post my code.

```
public static LinkedHashMap<String, Credentials> cred = new LinkedHashMap<>();
public String strAdr;
public InetAddress address;
public String username;
public boolean admin;
public Credentials(InetAddress adr, String username, boolean admin){
    this.strAdr = String.valueOf(adr);
    this.address = adr;
    this.username = username;
    this.admin = admin;
}
public void register(){
   cred.put(this.strAdr, this);
}
```

now just use `exchange.getRemoteAddress().getAddress()` for the adr varible

Comment: your answer is missing how to integrate this with HttpServer.

Comment: Ah ye, what u want to do is create a new Credentials class then register it when someone tries to login and at every page u want the session like code. Verify if the ip matches one from the hash map in this class. Feel free to use my project as a base. https://github.com/yankees88888g/website-mod/blob/master/src/main/java/net/web/fabric/http/website/handlers/LoginHandler.java